# What's the word for "synonyms of a phrase"?

Tags: grammar, dictionaries

I'm looking for multiple ways to say "*Call the Police*". When searching the thesaurus, I couldn't find anything. In my head, I can come up with "*report to the authorities*", or "*report a crime*", but I don't know the word for these phrases so that I can do more digging and find more examples.

Answer (score 2):

I believe "paraphrase" as a noun is the goose you're after.

Answer (score 0):

The word is still **synonym**.

Following is [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synonym) definition of the word. I am adding my own emphasis to *expressions* and *phrase*.

> **1** : one of two or more words or ***expressions*** of the same language that have the same or nearly the same meaning in some or all senses
> **2 a** : a word or ***phrase*** that by association is held to embody something (such as a concept or quality)
>        // a tyrant whose name has become a *synonym* for oppression

---

Note that the second and third example phrases in the question are not synonymous with the first (or even with each other).

The following are synonyms of *call the police*:

- *contact the cops*
- *get in touch with the authorities*

But these are not:

- *report to the authorities*
- *report a crime*

In the original phrase, nothing has actually been said about a report being made, nor about a crime having been committed. It describes a simple action, but makes no assumptions about *why* the action should be performed.